# GIT Staging Environment workflow - Merging

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

I have a remote Branch called "Develop", every new developer should clone this branch and push the changes to it when done, on the server what i see after pushing is the two branches the new one from the developer and the origin/develop .

so i have to merge the new branches to the develop branch everytime. actually i am new to git and am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is very unclear: "on the server what i see after pushing is the two branches the new one from the developer and the origin/develop". Could you please clarify? Are developers working on their own machines, or directly on your staging server?

Comment: they are working on their machines, let say a new developer created a local branch called "local", after pushing the local branch to the remote repo , i get local and develop so i have to merge them each time to have the developer's changes. is it clear now ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to push a local branch to an arbitrary remote branch. To push a local branch called `foobar` to the branch `develop` on the remote named `origin`, a developer may run

```
git push origin foobar:develop
```

From [the documentation for `git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> ### Synopsis
>
> ```
> git push ... [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
> ```

And later we see what `<refspec>` is:

> `<refspec>...`
>
> Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.
>
> The `<src>` is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as `master~4` or `HEAD` (see [gitrevisions(7)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html)).
>
> The `<dst>` tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this push. Arbitrary expressions cannot be used here, an actual ref must be named. If `git push [<repository>]` without any `<refspec>` argument is set to update some ref at the destination with `<src>` with `remote.<repository>.push` configuration variable, `:<dst>` part can be omitted---such a push will update a ref that `<src>` normally updates without any `<refspec>` on the command line. Otherwise, missing `:<dst>` means to update the same ref as the `<src>`.

Comment: It is typical to have the person merging be separate from the developer pushing their own dev branch.  Otherwise developers can conflict with one another and repeatedly attempt to push conflicting changes directly to the shared branch.  Use whatever process works best for you, but this answer as described essentially cuts out any in-repo awareness of merges being approved.  Therefore if you get developer conflicts, untangling the knot becomes more difficult.

Comment: @JoeAtzberger, good point about merging. This answer shows how to push to a differently named remote branch, nothing more. Developers should regularly `fetch` from `origin:develop` and merge these changes into their own. But that's no different from working in *any* shared branch. Based on the name I assumed (maybe erroneously) that the `develop` branch would be reviewed and periodically merged into another branch (`master`?) by a more senior team member (possibly the OP).